# Create release subbranch

Tags: git

**[simplified question (hopefully)]**

I have a master branch with files A, B, C, and D.
I want to have the following branching structure

```
master
|- branch1
|- branch2
|- branch3
```

where

- master contains file A
- branch1 contains files A and B
- branch2 contains files A and C
- branch3 contains files A and D

If I branch branch1, branch2, and branch3 from master, all branches will contain A, B, C, and D.
I could then
remove C and D from branch1,
remove B and D from branch2, and
remove B and C from branch3.
Then I could merge branch1, branch2, and branch3 into master.
That should work, right?
However, I have to delete B, C, and D each two times from different branches: can this be optimized so that I do not need to delete a file multiple times?

**[version1]**

I have a java/git project and, as of now, I only have a master branch.
I would now like to set up a release branch in a suitable way now by excluding parts of the code (some files but also some methods from certain files).

I could

- create a development branch from the master branch,
- create a release branch from the development branch, and
- delete elements from the release branch as needed.

But I imagine that merging changes on the development branch later into the release branch would be problematic when there are delete/modify conflicts.

I would follow a tutorial on that but did not find one.
Any ideas on how to do this in a reasonable and simple (I am not much of git poweruser) way?

[more info]

Basically, my code can be understood as a core part on which multiple modules operate.
Ideally, I should have created a branch for the core and one branch for each module.
However, now with the release problem, I also would need subbranches that hide parts of each branch.

```
src/core/Main.java
src/core/Helper.java
src/modA/FeatureA.java
src/modA/ExperimentalFeatureA.java
src/modB/FeatureB.java
src/modB/ExperimentalFeatureB.java
```

**[version2]**

I believe that I may want to have a structure like below where the branches core_dev, moduleA_dev, and moduleB_dev contain additional stuff not to be merged into core, moduleA, and moduleB.
Then I would need to check what to merge every time when merging a *_dev branch.
But, how to set this up? I guess the following would work with the extra effort to delete the same things in different branches in step 2.

- branch as described below but omit moduleA, moduleA_dev, moduleB, and moduleB_dev branches.
- delete additional material in core
- merge core into development
- merge development into release
- merge release into master
- branch moduleA from core, branch moduleA_dev from moduleA
- branch moduleB from core, branch moduleB_dev from moduleB
- somehow! merge core_dev into moduleA_dev and moduleB_dev without changing moduleA and moduleB

But does it make sense to do this differently?

```
master
|- release
   |- development
      |- core
          + src/core/Main.java
         |- core_dev
             + src/core/Helper.java
         |- moduleA
             + src/modA/FeatureA.java
            |- moduleA_dev
                + src/modA/ExperimentalFeatureA.java
         |- moduleB
             + src/modB/FeatureB.java
            |- moduleB_dev
                + src/modB/ExperimentalFeatureB.java
```

Comment: Why is the presence of core parts in a modA-specific branch a problem? You can definitely have a branch that's focused on changing stuff about modA and not care about core and modB being present as well.
Having related but structurally different content on different branches is quite tricky to do right and not usually worth it (especially when you want to easily merge one way or another).
Could you explain what your underlying goal is (this might be a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info))

Comment: I have added a section to explain how I could imagine doing it but at least one step is not clear to me how to do it.. Basically, I want to clean up and split my code into core, moduleA, and moduleB and the "dirty" private versions core_dev, moduleA_dev, and moduleB_dev; then the release should only have core, moduleA, and moduleB in it...

Comment: To me this sounds like `moduleA` and `moduleB` should really be separate repositories, as they don't share any code with `core` in your example.

Comment: What is a "subbranch"?

Comment: Did you already tried to implement [GitFlow](https://lucamezzalira.com/2014/03/10/git-flow-vs-github-flow/) to your project? Or you looking for a specific modified version of git methodology?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to implement GitFlow right now. Right now I only have the master branch containing also stuff that should only be in feature branches that should never be merged into master/development/release. My problem is how to create the feature branches such that I do not need to delete the same stuff multiple times..

Comment: @RonnieMarksch: I still don't quite understand why your feature branches have a substantially different structure than your main branch. Normally they have the same structure and only differ in the specific content. A feature branch *normally* is just a somewhat small deviation of the main branch, not an entirely different structure. That doesn't mean that it can't be done, but you must understand that you're doing something that's at least somewhat unusual.

Comment: Since I lack git expertise, using git in a strange way indicates that I am using it wrong. But maybe there is still a misunderstanding. I tried to simplified my question. Basically, I have a GitFlow branching structure in mind that I want to obtain from a non-branched (only master) repo.

Comment: I suppose now that I need cherry-picking; adjust one branch and cherry pick from the others; then N deletions are just one deletion and N-1 cherry pickings.